# 2004 Chevrolet Avalanche surface mount component identification

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image][image: photo of instrument cluster]

My instrument cluster stopped working and when I plug it in, I smell some burning. I found this component smoking and seems to be the source of the trouble. Can anyone please help me identify what it is?

Comment: the smoking component is probably overheating because of the problem at another location ... why is the component of interest taking up less than 1% of the picture?

Comment: Maybe a capacitor?  Hard to tell from so far out.  Try desoldering it and see if the board starts working again.

Comment: It seem to me a burnt LED. Is there some optical conduct (acrylic part) above it? But, as I said above, you should not risk to ruin your panel putting inexperienced hands in it.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from this scale - It seems to be white so it could be another SMT LED?
I would try desoldering the component and see if the rest starts working then.

Comment: The component is silver in color and not an LED. I have also tried desoldering it but nothing work after that.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to tell if you took a picture a little closeup. But from what I can see it looks like a surface mount led got cooked. It could be a capacitor as well. Try removing that component and see if it works. Check the inputs to this board before plugging it in just in case. 
Edit 1: after looking at the closeup picture

https://www.budgetronics.eu/en/capacitors/smd-0805-ceramic-capacitors/smd-ceramic-capacitors-0805-1-2pf/a-13732-10000114
Looks like one of these capacitors, not sure about the value.

Comment: Thank you @theCNN, I have added a more close up picture of the component.

Comment: It's not an led probably a capacitor I'm out off by the white colour, it is shally a beige colour.  Could be one of these https://www.budgetronics.eu/en/capacitors/smd-0805-ceramic-capacitors/smd-ceramic-capacitors-0805-1-2pf/a-13732-10000114  not sure about its value

Comment: It could be an essential part of some ic or some other circuit that requires a capacitor to operate.

Comment: Yes it is not an led, I tried that and didn't get any change.

Comment: Looks like a capacitor.